# PROTRACTOR - Element is not attached to the page document

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

So guys, the same problem as a lot of people! When i trying to interact (Click) on a element into the page a have problems with the error:

**Error Message**

> "Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
>   document"

I undertood the concept of the page changing the DOM, but i really cannot solve the problem. Some advices? 
(**element with error:  *await processoLista.click();***)

````
    console.log('Testing Pesquisa Assunto ...');

    beforeAll(async function () {
        await browser.get(browser.params.URL_PROCESSO).then(function () {
            const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        })

    });
    it('Deve escolher um ASSUNTO PRINCIPAL e verificar os resultados', async function () {

        try {
            if (await browser.findElements(by.id('filtro_assuntos')).toEqual(""));
        } catch{
            const btnMaisFiltros = element(by.id('maisFiltros'))
            const placeAssunto = element(by.css('[placeholder = "Assunto"]'))
            const listAssuntos = element.all(by.className('mat-option-text')).get(2)
            const habilitaAssuntoP = element(by.className('mat-slide-toggle-bar'))
            const aplicar = element(by.className("aplicar"))
            const processoPainel = element(by.className('cdk-overlay-pane'))
            const classText = element(by.className('texto'))
            const assunto = element(by.partialLinkText('Abandono'))

            await btnMaisFiltros.click();
            await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(placeAssunto));
            await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(placeAssunto));
            await placeAssunto.click();

            await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(listAssuntos));
            await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(listAssuntos));
            await listAssuntos.click();

            await habilitaAssuntoP.click();

            await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(aplicar));
            await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(aplicar));
            await aplicar.click();


            const processoLista = await element.all(by.className('identificacao')).get(0);
            await browser.wait(EC.titleContains('.'));
            await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(processoLista));
            await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(processoLista));
            await processoLista.click();//HE CANNOT CLICK HERE! SOMETIMES HE CAN AND SOMETIMES I HAVE THE ERROR


            await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(classText));
            await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(assunto));
            expect(await assunto.getText()).toContain('Abandono')

        }
    })```
````

Comment: which line is causing the issue? can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: @Sureshmani the element with error is  await processoLista.click();

Comment: I believe there is some other process / event happening after aplicar.click() which impacts the next element-  processoLista .  Did you try adding a static wait? Thought it is not recommended, it is easier to isolate the issue with this wait.